# reference to 'distance' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, visual-c++

While compiling the following code i am getting the error as

**reference to 'distance' is ambiguous**

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class distance
{
    int feet,inches;
    distance():feet(0),inches(0)
    {

    }
    distance(int f,int i):feet(f),inches(i)
    {
    }

    void show()

    {
        cout<<"feet  "<<feet;
        cout<<endl<<"inches   "<<inches;
    }

    distance operator + (distance) ;
};

distance distance::operator + (distance d)
{
    int f,i;
    f=feet+d.feet;
    i=inches+d.inches;
    return distance(f,i);
}

int main()
{
    distance d1;
    distance d2(2,3),d3(7,5);;
d1=d2+d3;
d1.show();
}
```

can anyone help me with the error.
And provide me the solution and as to why i am getting this error.

Comment: Is this your real code? Currently, the `distance` constructor is private.

Comment: Your `distance` is ambiguous because of `using namespace std;`, there is `std::distance` function. Never do this.

Answer (score 14):

And this is why [`using namespace std;` should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Your class `distance` is clashing with the standard function [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).  Get rid of the `using namespace std;` and if you are going to be using a standard component use `std::name_of_thing` every time you use it or you can use `using std::name_of_thing`.

Answer (score 1):

Your class name is clashing with another symbol from the namespace, changing your class name to something else like `Distance` would be one *possible* solution.

Comment: I'd argue that removing `using namespace std;` is a better fix.

Comment: Well, whatever the argument for the fix is (and yes, I would tend to agree with you here), identifying the problem is probably more important here